# countdown timer Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

need to implement a timer with the following idea: the user has a form to submit their data to the Answer database, which is handled by the QuizTake class. This class contains views that perform various functions such as validation, user authentication, data submission to the server, and data saving. The functionality you want to implement is as follows: create a countdown function where, while the timer is running, the answer submission form is enabled and the user can use it. When the timer expires, the form saves its content and forcefully saves it to the Answer database, and input into the form is no longer accessible. How can this be implemented?

view

```
class QuizTake(FormView):
    form_class = QuestionForm
    template_name = 'cansole/question.html'
    result_template_name = 'result.html'
    single_complete_template_name = 'single_complete.html'
    timer_duration = 3600

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, url=self.kwargs['quiz_name'])
        if self.quiz.draft and not request.user.has_perm('quiz.change_quiz'):
            raise PermissionDenied

        self.logged_in_user = self.request.user.is_authenticated

        if self.logged_in_user:
            self.sitting = Sitting.objects.user_sitting(request.user, self.quiz)
        else:
            self.sitting = self.anon_load_sitting()  ##сделать редирект на логин

        if self.sitting is False:
            return render(request, self.single_complete_template_name)

        self.start_time = datetime.now()
        self.timer_expired = False
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def check_timer_expired(self):
        elapsed_time = (datetime.now() - self.start_time).total_seconds()
        return elapsed_time >= self.timer_duration

    def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.logged_in_user:
            self.question = self.sitting.get_first_question()
            self.progress = self.sitting.progress()

        else:
            self.question = self.anon_next_question()
            self.progress = self.anon_sitting_progress()  ##сделать редирект на логин

        if self.check_timer_expired():
            kwargs['disabled'] = True  # Отключаем поле формы, передавая аргумент 'disabled'

        return self.form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['question'] = self.question
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):

        if self.logged_in_user:
            self.form_valid_user(form)
            if self.sitting.get_first_question() is False:
                return redirect('index')  ##сделать редирект на ошибку
        else:
            self.form_valid_anon(form)
            if not self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()]:
                return redirect('error')

        self.request.POST = {}

        return super().get(self, self.request)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        elapsed_time = (datetime.now() - self.start_time).total_seconds()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['question'] = self.question
        context['quiz'] = self.quiz
        context['user'] = self.request.user
        context['timer_expired'] = self.check_timer_expired()


        if hasattr(self, 'previous'):
            context['previous'] = self.previous
        if hasattr(self, 'progress'):
            context['progress'] = self.progress
        return context

    def form_valid_user(self, form):
        progress, c = Progress.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user)
        guess = form.cleaned_data['answer']

        answer = Answer(
            user=self.request.user,
            question=self.question,
            content=guess,
            quiz=self.quiz

        )
        answer.save()
        if self.check_timer_expired():
            self.sitting.mark_quiz_complete()

        self.sitting.add_user_answer(self.question, guess)
        self.sitting.remove_first_question()

    def final_result_user(self):
        results = {
            'quiz': self.quiz,
            'score': self.sitting.get_current_score(),
            'max_score': self.sitting.get_max_score(),
            'percent': self.sitting.get_percent_correct(),
            'sitting': self.sitting,
            'previous': self.previous,
        }

        self.sitting.mark_quiz_complete()

        if self.quiz.answers_at_end:
            # Получаем список вопросов с ответами
            results['questions'] = self.sitting.get_questions(with_answers=True)
            results['incorrect_questions'] = self.sitting.get_incorrect_questions()

        if not self.quiz.exam_paper:
            self.sitting.delete()

        return render(self.request, self.result_template_name, results)
```

html

```
{% extends 'cansole/admin.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %} {{ quiz.title }} {% endblock %}  <!-- тут  -->
{% block description %} {{ quiz.title }} - {{ quiz.description }} {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% if previous.answers %}

<p class="muted"><small>{% trans "The previous question" %}:</small></p>
<p>{{ previous.previous_question }}</p>

{% if previous.previous_outcome %}
<div class="alert alert-success">
    {% else %}
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        {% endif %}
        <p><small>
            {% trans "Your answer was" %} </small>
            <strong>
                {{ previous.previous_outcome|yesno:"correct,incorrect" }}
            </strong>
        </p>

    </div>

    {% include 'correct_answer.html' %}

    <p><strong>{% trans "Explanation" %}:</strong></p>
    <div class="well " style="background-color: #fcf8e3;">
        <p>{{ previous.previous_question.explanation }}</p>
    </div>

    <hr>

    {% endif %}

    <br/>

    {% if question %}

    {% if progress %}
    <div style="float: right;">
        {% trans "Question" %} {{ progress.0|add:1 }} {% trans "of" %} {{ progress.1 }}
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    <p>
        <small class="muted">{% trans "Question category" %}:</small>
        <strong>{{ question.category }}</strong>
    </p>

    <p class="lead">{{ question.content }}</p>

    {% if question.figure %}
    <img src="{{ question.figure.url }}" alt="{{ question.content }}"/>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="{{ question.id }}">

        <ul class="list-group">
            {% for answer in form.answer %}
            <li class="list-group-item">
                {{ answer }}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Check' %}" class="btn btn-outline-success">
    </form>

    {% endif %}
<p>Time remaining: {{ time_remaining }} seconds</p>
{% endblock %}
```

models

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import re
import json

from django.contrib import auth
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError, ImproperlyConfigured
from django.core.validators import (
    MaxValueValidator, validate_comma_separated_integer_list,
)
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.utils.timezone import now
from six import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager



@python_2_unicode_compatible
class CategoryManager(models.Manager):

    def new_category(self, category):
        new_category = self.create(category=re.sub('\s+', '-', category)
                                   .lower())

        new_category.save()
        return new_category


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Category(models.Model):

    category = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_("Category"),
        max_length=250, blank=True,
        unique=True, null=True)

    objects = CategoryManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Category")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Categories")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class SubCategory(models.Model):

    sub_category = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_("Sub-Category"),
        max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name=_("Category"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    objects = CategoryManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Sub-Category")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Sub-Categories")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sub_category + " (" + self.category.category + ")"

class Quiz(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_("Название игры"),
        max_length=60, blank=False)

    description = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_("Описание игры"),
        blank=True, help_text=_("Описание игр"))

    url = models.SlugField(
        max_length=60, blank=False,
        help_text=_("Придумайте адрес, по которому будет ссылка на игру"),
        verbose_name=_("Адрес, по которому будет ссылка на игру"))

    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='quiz/images/',
        verbose_name=_("Изображение"),
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name=_("Лига"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    answers_at_end = models.BooleanField(
        blank=False, default=False,
        help_text=_("Выводить результаты игры после окончания?"
                    " Результаты"),
        verbose_name=_("Результаты после игры"))

    exam_paper = models.BooleanField(
        blank=False, default=False,
        help_text=_("Если да, выводит результаты игры после окончания?"
                    " финальная таблица по окончанию"
                    " Результаты игры"),
        verbose_name=_("Exam Paper"))

    single_attempt = models.BooleanField(
        blank=False, default=False,
        help_text=_("If yes, only one attempt by"
                    " a user will be permitted."
                    " Non users cannot sit this exam."),
        verbose_name=_("Single Attempt"))

    success_text = models.TextField(
        blank=True, help_text=_("Displayed if user passes."),
        verbose_name=_("Success Text"))

    draft = models.BooleanField(
        blank=True, default=False,
        verbose_name=_("Draft"),
        help_text=_("If yes, the quiz is not displayed"
                    " in the quiz list and can only be"
                    " taken by users who can edit"
                    " quizzes."))

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        # Преобразование URL-адреса, замена пробелов на дефисы и приведение к нижнему регистру
        self.url = re.sub('\s+', '-', self.url).lower()

        # Удаление всех символов, кроме букв, цифр, и дефисов из URL-адреса
        self.url = ''.join(letter for letter in self.url if letter.isalnum() or letter == '-')

        # Если разрешена только одна попытка, установить флаг exam_paper в True
        if self.single_attempt is True:
            self.exam_paper = True

        # Проверка, что значение pass_mark не превышает 100


        super(Quiz, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Quiz")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Quizzes")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_questions(self):
        return self.question_set.all().select_subclasses()

    @property
    def get_max_score(self):
        return self.get_questions().count()

    def anon_score_id(self):
        return str(self.id) + "_score"

    def anon_q_list(self):
        return str(self.id) + "_q_list"

    def anon_q_data(self):
        return str(self.id) + "_data"

class ProgressManager(models.Manager):

    def new_progress(self, user):
        new_progress = self.create(user=user,
                                   score="")
        new_progress.save()
        return new_progress


class Progress(models.Model):
    """
    Progress is used to track an individual signed in users score on different
    quiz's and categories

    Data stored in csv using the format:
        category, score, possible, category, score, possible, ...
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_("User"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    score = models.CharField(max_length=1024,
                             verbose_name=_("Score"),
                             validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list])

    objects = ProgressManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("User Progress")
        verbose_name_plural = _("User progress records")

    @property
    def list_all_cat_scores(self):
        """
        Returns a dict in which the key is the category name and the item is
        a list of three integers.

        The first is the number of questions correct,
        the second is the possible best score,
        the third is the percentage correct.

        The dict will have one key for every category that you have defined
        """
        score_before = self.score
        output = {}

        for cat in Category.objects.all():
            to_find = re.escape(cat.category) + r",(\d+),(\d+),"
            #  group 1 is score, group 2 is highest possible

            match = re.search(to_find, self.score, re.IGNORECASE)

            if match:
                score = int(match.group(1))
                possible = int(match.group(2))

                try:
                    percent = int(round((float(score) / float(possible))
                                        * 100))
                except:
                    percent = 0

                output[cat.category] = [score, possible, percent]

            else:  # if category has not been added yet, add it.
                self.score += cat.category + ",0,0,"
                output[cat.category] = [0, 0]

        if len(self.score) > len(score_before):
            # If a new category has been added, save changes.
            self.save()

        return output

    def update_score(self, question, score_to_add=0, possible_to_add=0):
        """
        Pass in question object, amount to increase score
        and max possible.

        Does not return anything.
        """
        category_test = Category.objects.filter(category=question.category)\
                                        .exists()

        if any([item is False for item in [category_test,
                                           score_to_add,
                                           possible_to_add,
                                           isinstance(score_to_add, int),
                                           isinstance(possible_to_add, int)]]):
            return _("error"), _("category does not exist or invalid score")

        to_find = re.escape(str(question.category)) +\
            r",(?P<score>\d+),(?P<possible>\d+),"

        match = re.search(to_find, self.score, re.IGNORECASE)

        if match:
            updated_score = int(match.group('score')) + abs(score_to_add)
            updated_possible = int(match.group('possible')) +\
                abs(possible_to_add)

            new_score = ",".join(
                [
                    str(question.category),
                    str(updated_score),
                    str(updated_possible), ""
                ])

            # swap old score for the new one
            self.score = self.score.replace(match.group(), new_score)
            self.save()

        else:
            #  if not present but existing, add with the points passed in
            self.score += ",".join(
                [
                    str(question.category),
                    str(score_to_add),
                    str(possible_to_add),
                    ""
                ])
            self.save()

    def show_exams(self):
        """
        Finds the previous quizzes marked as 'exam papers'.
        Returns a queryset of complete exams.
        """
        return Sitting.objects.filter(user=self.user, complete=True)

class SittingManager(models.Manager):

    def new_sitting(self, user, quiz):
        question_set = quiz.question_set.all().select_subclasses()
        question_set = [item.id for item in question_set]

        if len(question_set) == 0:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured('Question set of the quiz is empty. Please configure questions properly')


        questions = ",".join(map(str, question_set)) + ","

        new_sitting = self.create(user=user,
                                  quiz=quiz,
                                  question_order=questions,
                                  question_list=questions,
                                  incorrect_questions="",
                                  current_score=0,
                                  complete=False,
                                  user_answers='{}')
        return new_sitting

    def user_sitting(self, user, quiz):
        if quiz.single_attempt is True and self.filter(user=user, quiz=quiz, complete=True).exists():
            return False

        try:
            sitting = self.get(user=user, quiz=quiz, complete=False)
        except Sitting.DoesNotExist:
            sitting = self.new_sitting(user, quiz)
        except Sitting.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            sitting = self.filter(user=user, quiz=quiz, complete=False)[0]
        return sitting


class Sitting(models.Model):
    """
    Used to store the progress of logged in users sitting a quiz.
    Replaces the session system used by anon users.

    Question_order is a list of integer pks of all the questions in the
    quiz, in order.

    Question_list is a list of integers which represent id's of
    the unanswered questions in csv format.

    Incorrect_questions is a list in the same format.

    Sitting deleted when quiz finished unless quiz.exam_paper is true.

    User_answers is a json object in which the question PK is stored
    with the answer the user gave.
    """

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_("User"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, verbose_name=_("Quiz"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    question_order = models.CharField(
        max_length=1024,
        verbose_name=_("Question Order"),
        validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list])

    question_list = models.CharField(
        max_length=1024,
        verbose_name=_("Question List"),
        validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list])

    incorrect_questions = models.CharField(
        max_length=1024,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_("Incorrect questions"),
        validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list])

    current_score = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_("Current Score"))

    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False,
                                   verbose_name=_("Complete"))

    user_answers = models.TextField(blank=True, default='{}',
                                    verbose_name=_("User Answers"))

    start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                 verbose_name=_("Start"))

    end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("End"))

    objects = SittingManager()

    class Meta:
        permissions = (("view_sittings", _("Can see completed exams.")),)

    def get_first_question(self):
        """
        Returns the next question.
        If no question is found, returns False
        Does NOT remove the question from the front of the list.
        """
        if not self.question_list:
            return False

        first, _ = self.question_list.split(',', 1)
        question_id = int(first)
        return Question.objects.get_subclass(id=question_id)

    def remove_first_question(self):
        if not self.question_list:
            return

        _, others = self.question_list.split(',', 1)
        self.question_list = others
        self.save()

    def add_to_score(self, points):
        self.current_score += int(points)
        self.save()

    @property
    def get_current_score(self):
        return self.current_score

    def _question_ids(self):
        return [int(n) for n in self.question_order.split(',') if n]

    @property
    def get_percent_correct(self):
        dividend = float(self.current_score)
        divisor = len(self._question_ids())
        if divisor < 1:
            return 0            # prevent divide by zero error

        if dividend > divisor:
            return 100

        correct = int(round((dividend / divisor) * 100))

        if correct >= 1:
            return correct
        else:
            return 0

    def mark_quiz_complete(self):
        self.complete = True
        self.end = now()
        self.save()

    def add_incorrect_question(self, question):
        """
        Adds uid of incorrect question to the list.
        The question object must be passed in.
        """
        if len(self.incorrect_questions) > 0:
            self.incorrect_questions += ','
        self.incorrect_questions += str(question.id) + ","
        if self.complete:
            self.add_to_score(-1)
        self.save()

    @property
    def get_incorrect_questions(self):
        """
        Returns a list of non empty integers, representing the pk of
        questions
        """
        return [int(q) for q in self.incorrect_questions.split(',') if q]

    def remove_incorrect_question(self, question):
        current = self.get_incorrect_questions
        current.remove(question.id)
        self.incorrect_questions = ','.join(map(str, current))
        self.add_to_score(1)
        self.save()

    @property
    def check_if_passed(self):
        return self.get_percent_correct >= self.quiz.pass_mark

    @property
    def result_message(self):
        if self.check_if_passed:
            return self.quiz.success_text
        else:
            return self.quiz.fail_text

    def add_user_answer(self, question, guess):
        current = json.loads(self.user_answers)
        current[question.id] = guess
        self.user_answers = json.dumps(current)
        self.save()

    def get_questions(self, with_answers=False):
        question_ids = self._question_ids()
        questions = sorted(
            self.quiz.question_set.filter(id__in=question_ids)
                                  .select_subclasses(),
            key=lambda q: question_ids.index(q.id))

        if with_answers:
            user_answers = json.loads(self.user_answers)
            for question in questions:
                question.user_answer = user_answers[str(question.id)]

        return questions

    @property
    def questions_with_user_answers(self):
        return {
            q: q.user_answer for q in self.get_questions(with_answers=True)
        }

    @property
    def get_max_score(self):
        return len(self._question_ids())

    def progress(self):
        """
        Returns the number of questions answered so far and the total number of
        questions.
        """
        answered = len(json.loads(self.user_answers))
        total = self.get_max_score
        return answered, total

class Question(models.Model):
    """
    Base class for all question types.
    Shared properties placed here.
    """

    quiz = models.ManyToManyField(Quiz,
                                  verbose_name=_("Quiz"),
                                  blank=True)

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 verbose_name=_("Category"),
                                 blank=True,
                                 null=True,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, verbose_name=_("Sub-Category"),
                                     blank=True,
                                     null=True,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    figure = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d',
                               blank=True,
                               null=True,
                               verbose_name=_("Figure"))

    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000,
                               blank=False,
                               help_text=_("Enter the question text that "
                                           "you want displayed"),
                               verbose_name=_('Question'))

    explanation = models.TextField(max_length=2000,
                                   blank=True,
                                   help_text=_("Explanation to be shown "
                                               "after the question has "
                                               "been answered."),
                                   verbose_name=_('Explanation'))

    objects = InheritanceManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Question")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Questions")
        ordering = ['category']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, verbose_name=_("Question"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000,
                               blank=False,
                               help_text=_("Enter the answer text that "
                                           "you want displayed"),
                               verbose_name=_("Ответ"))

    correct = models.BooleanField(blank=False,
                                  default=False,
                                  help_text=_("Is this a correct answer?"),
                                  verbose_name=_("Correct"))

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, verbose_name=_("Пользователи"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, verbose_name=_("Quiz"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Answer")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Answers")
```

Comment: Honestly I do not see this happening without using javascript or some other front end "magic". Remember: Django is your backend and can only "do stuff" when you send a request to the server. Especially the part "send a request after 10 minutes" that forcefully submits the answer is impossible as far as I know impossible to do.